# Some examples of functions relating to the behavior of $C({\Bbb R}/{\Bbb Z},\Bbb C)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n,f \in C({\Bbb R}/{\Bbb Z},\Bbb C)$, give examples individually such that

(1)$f_n \to f$in the $L^2$ metric and pointwise, but not uniformly

(2)$f_n \to f$in the $L^2$ metric, but not pointwise

(3)$f_n \to f$in the $L^2$ pointwise, but not in the $L^2$ metric

My attempt: I am just a bit lost on how to make such functions. I was attempting to use $f_n= \frac{1}{nx}\sin(n\pi x) f=\frac{1}{x}cos(n\pi x)$ for (1) but then realized that they are not periodic. and for constant functions I don't feel they can fit into any of the category above.

Thanks for the help

Side note: The metric for $L^2$ is $ d_{L^2}(f_n,f)= (\int_{[0,1]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and the space $C({\Bbb R}/{\Bbb Z},\Bbb C)$ is the space of complex-valued continuous Z-periodic functions

Comment: I presume you mean $d_{L^2}(f_n,f)= (\int_0^1 |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: yes I am sorry that was an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these problems can be solved with $f(x) = 0$ and $f_n$ equal to a function which is mostly $0$ but has a "peak" on a small interval. The common theme here is that one type of convergence doesn't imply another. The reason is that the $L^2$ norm cares about both the values a function takes and the "size" (measure) of the sets on which it takes particular values. Pointwise convergence, on the other hand, only cares about the values of the functions. You can control these two factors in order to obtain one type of convergence but not another (e.g. you can make a function take really large values but still have small $L^2$ norm by making the sets on which the function is large have small measure). The idea is to control the pointwise convergence with the positions and widths of the peaks. You can independently control the $L^2$ norm by varying the heights of the peaks. By setting $f(x) = 0$, the convergence $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ simply becomes the statement that the $L^2$ norm $\Vert f_n \Vert_2$ approaches $0$. Indeed, one can usually "convert" a solution $f_n,f$ to problems like this to a solution where the limit is $0$ by just replacing $f_n$ with $f_n - f$.

(1): If we choose the $f_n$ to be uniformly bounded, then pointwise convergence will imply $L^2$ convergence by the dominated convergence theorem. So we want uniformly bounded functions $f_n$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise but not uniformly. If we choose the $f_n$ such that there is always some point $x_n \in [0,1)$ such that $f_n(x_n)$ and $f(x_n)$ are some fixed distance apart, then we cannot have uniform convergence. Imagine functions $f_n$ which are equal to $0$ except for a small triangular peak of height $1$ on a small interval $I_n$. If each peak has height $1$, then at the peak point $x_n$ we have
$$f(x_n) - f(x) = f(x_n) = 1.$$
On the other hand, if you choose the $I_n$ so that each point in $[0,1)$ is $I_n$ for only finitely many of the $f_n$, you'll get pointwise convergence. An example would be to take $I_n = [1/2^n,1/2^{n+1}]$.

(2): Let $f(x) = 0$. By taking the $f_n$ to be functions which have a bump of height $1$ on a small set $I_n$, we will obtain the desired $L^2$ convergence, but if the peak point $c$ is the same for all the $f_n$, the pointwise convergence will fail at $c$. For instance, let $I_n = [1/2 - 1/2^{n+1},1/2 + 1/2^{n+1}]$ and let $f_n(x)$ be a function with an isosceles triangular peak of height $1$ on $I_n$ (so that $f(1/2) = 1$) and $0$ elsewhere.

(3): In this case the functions $f_n$ cannot be uniformly bounded, or else dominated convergence would give you $L^2$ convergence from pointwise. Again take $f(x) = 0$. By making the $f_n$ large on sets $I_n$ of small measure and zero elsewhere, we can make the $f_n$ all have the samme nonzero $L^2$ norm, thus $f_n \not\to f$ in $L^2$. Again by choosing the $I_n$ so that for each $x \in [0,1]$, we have $x \in I_n$ for only finitely many $n$ ensures pointwise convergence. As an example, take $I_n$ as in (1) and consider a function which is $0$ outside of $I_n$ and has an isosceles triangular peak on the intervals $I_n$ of height $2^{n+1}$. Let $f_n(x)$ be the square root of this function. Then $\Vert f_n \Vert_2^2$ is simply the area of the triangle, which is
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I was able to gain more insight on how the $L^2$ behaves. Very helpful.

Comment: May I ask what the notation $\chi$ means?

Comment: $\chi_E$ stands for characteristic function of $E$. This is not a continuous function so the examples in this answer have to me modified to make them continuous.

Comment: I have been able to understand how these functions shows convergence or pointwise convergence. However, I am not quite getting why the functions $f_n$ is periodic. I am also not sure what $I_n$ means. I know the constant function $f(x)=0$ is periodic though. Do you mind giving me some more explanation on that? Much appreciated.

Comment: Any function $g$ on $[0,1)$ uniquely determines a $1$-periodic function $h$ defined by $h(x) =g([x])$,where $[x]$ is the fractional part of $x$. The function $h$ is continuous if and only if $g$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to 1^-}g(x) = g(0)$